# HTML classes and IDs with with $ or non alpha numeric characters

Tags: asp.net, xhtml, w3c-validation

I'm looking at some site code on an XHTML doctype and from what I'm seeing the framework is ASP.net. The IDs in the HTML has a "$" in there.

For example:

```
<img id="$ct100templateContent$SectionPanel1$ctl01$ctl02ctl00_templateContent_SectionPanel1_ctl01_ct999img" src="this.jpg"/>
```

From a W3C semantic point of view the "$" is not valid in an ID or Class.  IDs and classes can only contain alpha numeric characters in an XHTML doctype.

Is the the "$" a ASP.net naming convention referencing a web control or template item?

Comment: Go figure, MS would wee all over the standards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little confused how/why you're seeing dollar signs in the *id*.

When rendering a Web control into markup, ASP.NET generates the element's `id` and `name` attributes based on the Web control's `ID` property and its location in the control hierarchy. In short, certain controls - such as templated controls or repeating controls - act as *naming containers*. Such controls' `ID` property values are prefixed to their inner controls' `ID` property values when determining the `id` and `name` attributes.

For example, consider the following control hierarchy:

[image: Sample ASP.NET control hierarchy.]

Here, the Master Page (`ctl00`) and ContentPlaceHolder (`MainContent`) controls are naming containers. The `Age` TextBox Web control will have a rendered `id` of `clt00_MainContent_Age - namely, its own server-side`ID`property value prefixed with the`ID` values of its naming container ancestors.

But note how the rendered `id` is separating each naming container spot **with an underscore.** This is the default functionality in ASP.NET, so I am perplexed as to why you are seeing dollar signs in the `id` attribute. (When formulating the `name` attribute, ASP.NET separates each naming container spot with a dollar sign, but it shouldn't use $ when formulating the `id` attribute value.)

What version of ASP.NET are you using? Are you doing anything... weird? Like using custom controls and overriding the base `Control` class's `IdSeparator` property? If you are using ASP.NET 4, are you setting (either intentionally or unintentionally) the control's `ClientIDMode` property?

Comment: I'm not sure which version of ASP.NET they are using. From your explanation on how ids are formulated I'm thinking the ASP.NET developer made a mistake in generating the front end code.

Answer (score 0):

The $value stands for the level of which the control is embedded in your site/page. You can also change ClientIDMode to Static to make use of your own ID's.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ASP.NET uses the '$' symbol when it generates the IDs of controls based off the hierarchical page layout. ASP.NET does not use the '$' symbol in class names.